# in NEST, how do I dynamically build a query from a list of terms?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Say my user provides a list of search terms which I've collected into an array/list, and now I want to combine those OR-wise into a NEST query using MatchPhrase. How would I do that? The code for a (single) search term would look something like this:

```cs
var search = client.Search<ElasticRequirement>(s => s
.Query(q =>
    q.MatchPhrase(m => m.OnField(f => f.Title).Query(term.ToLower()).Slop(slop))
    || q.MatchPhrase(m => m.OnField(f => f.Description).Query(text).Slop(slop))
    )
   .LowercaseExpandedTerms()
   .Explain()
   .Query(q => q.Fuzzy(f => f.PrefixLength(1).OnField(c => c.Title).OnField(c => c.Description)))
);
```

This is fine, but I need to apply that same MatchPhrase filter once for each provided search term. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `bool` `should` expressions to build your query dynamically. I'll provide the complete solution below. Call `BuildQuery()` method with appropriate parameters.

```cs
ISearchResponse<ElasticRequirement> BuildQuery(IElasticClient client, IEnumerable<string> terms, int slop)
{
    return client.Search<ElasticRequirement>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Should(terms.Select(t => BuildPhraseQueryContainer(q, t, slop)).ToArray())))
        .LowercaseExpandedTerms()
        .Explain()
        .Query(q => q.Fuzzy(f => f.PrefixLength(1).OnField(c => c.Title).OnField(c => c.Description))));
}

QueryContainer BuildPhraseQueryContainer(QueryDescriptor<ElasticRequirement> qd, string term, int slop)
{
    return qd.MatchPhrase(m => m.OnField(f => f.Title).Query(term.ToLower()).Slop(slop)) ||
        qd.MatchPhrase(m => m.OnField(f => f.Description).Query(term.ToLower()).Slop(slop));
}
```

For `terms = {"term1", "term2", "term3"}` and `slop = 0`, the Elasticsearch search JSON command that will get built by my code is as under:

```
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": {
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "query": "term1",
                    "slop": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "description": {
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "query": "term1",
                    "slop": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": {
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "query": "term2",
                    "slop": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "description": {
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "query": "term2",
                    "slop": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": {
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "query": "term3",
                    "slop": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "description": {
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "query": "term3",
                    "slop": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can tweak this code such that all the `match` commands are under the same `should` node. I'll leave that up to you to figure out :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your thorough answer!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Really helped a lot.

Comment: NEST v 5.2 throws exception "querycontainer can only hold a single query already contains a matchphrasequerydescriptor".